# How can I use lists to simplify my Animation Nodes setup for multiple objects?

Tags: animation, animation-nodes

I'm trying to learn animation using Animation Nodes, and so far, I've achieved the result in the gif below:

[image]

`Explanation:` If the value of the current frame is less than (B), switch the material from RED to GREEN.

[image]

So, I created this setup for 4 objects (S-O-N-G), each with its set of nodes:

[image]

`My question is:` How to simplify this node tree using a list? In other words, instead of repeating the nodes 4 times, I want to streamline it into a single setup using a list.

The relationship of the lists is this:

[image]

How can I achieve this? I've been trying to learn from tutorials, but I've spent hours searching and still haven't figured out how to do it in my case.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I racked my brain, but I managed to find a solution!

1. I create a `Loop Input` node with two `new Iterators`: `Object List` and `Integer List`.
2. I connect the Iterators to my old setup where I would like to have the variables (in the image below, inside the white frame).

[image]

3. I list my objects by creating the `Collection Info` node (I placed all my objects inside a collection in the Outliner).
4. I list the numbers corresponding to the frames by creating the `Integer List` node.
5. I create an `Invoke Subprogram` node.
6. I connect the two lists (Objects + Numbers/Frames) to the Object List and Integer List inputs of the Invoke Subprogram.

[image]

Voila! :D